# Changing the output of \vref

Tags: cross-referencing, varioref

I'm using `\vref` for labels in my text. I'd like to change it in the output form X on p. Y instead of X on page Y. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are using the [`varioref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package. You have to redefine `\reftextfaraway`. Solution without [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{varioref}

\renewcommand*{\reftextfaraway}[1]{on p.~\pageref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}\label{sec:foo}

Some text.

\cleardoublepage

\section{bar}

See section~\vref{sec:foo}.

\end{document}
```

Solution with `babel`:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{varioref}

\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \renewcommand*{\reftextfaraway}[1]{on p.~\pageref{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}\label{sec:foo}

Some text.

\cleardoublepage

\section{bar}

See section~\vref{sec:foo}.

\end{document}
```

Output for both solutions (page 3):

[image]